# building VSIX project under x64 bit platform

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, vs-extensibility, badimageformatexception

The following steps:

1. Create new VSIX project in Visual Studio 2015     *(C# ->    Extensibility -> VSIX Project)*;
2. Switching the platform from 'Any CPU' to x64 in Configuration Manager;
3. Add new Custom Command *(Add New Item -> Visual C# -> Extensibility)*
4. Try to build.

And in this point we're having some error complaining about 'BadImageFormatException' (a screenshot is presented below). What is that? Is it just my machine or is it really impossible to build a visual studio extension under 64-bit?

*error : CreatePkgDef : error : BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly*

*error :    at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)*

*error :    at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)*

*error :    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.CreatePkgDef.ProcessAssembly(String fileName, Hive hive, PkgDefContext context, Boolean register, RegistrationMode mode)*

[image]

Comment: VSIXs run in-process and VS is still 32-bit only - so what would you hope to achieve?

Comment: Oh, that makes perfect sense. Thank you